# "File not found." appears often while navigating wp-admin

Tags: errors

I've been experiencing this issue with this specific website quite often. I moved it from a staging domain to the production domain and since it's been doing this. It did not do this on the staging domain (same server).

1. I did a find and replace on the database to ensure that the staging domain was replaced with the production domain.
2. I have flushed the permalinks.
3. I have increased PHP memory for this site

I can't point to a specific plugin. I've used these plugin before on many sites. Everything is up to date. I have not found a pattern to when it appears. If I click between the Posts, Media and Page tabs often enough it eventually happens. I also happens when interacting with the plugins section of the site.

After it has happened a refresh of the page brings it back.

Here are examples:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just searching and replacing often breaks things. WP stores a lot of data in a serialized array, meaning if the staging URL and prod URL are different numbers of characters, those serialized arrays will break. It's safer to use a plugin that handles updating the character counts as well as just the raw URLs.

Comment: Are you serving this domain from multiple machines? Or migrated it recently and forgotten to remove the old DNS records? If you have multiple servers DNS records for a domain it will rotate through them. Likewise if you're load balancing and one of the servers isn't setup

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks, that's good to know! I'll change my migration process going forward.

Comment: @TomJNowell No, this is being served from one machine. I migrated it from one domain to another on the same machine. Updated the DNS to point to the machine. No load balancing in place.

Comment: @WebElaine After having already done the search and replace (using MigrateWP plugin) is their anything else I can do to fix the issue?

Comment: I don't believe the cause of this problem lays in the WordPress/PHP area, this issue will be caused by something deeper down the stack, e.g. Apache/Nginx, or DNS. Are you sure when you added the DNS records that you removed the old ones? I very much doubt that WP expertise is going to be of much use to you here unless files are missing from your `wp-admin` folder. Verify and confirm that all files are intact and present. Also, you should make sure you changed the URL correctly, not via a search replace SQL query

Comment: Disabling mod_security on the server solved this issue. That being said I don't know why it was conflicting. Thanks for your help!